# Can we say "Tom, too / either" and "Him, too / either"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am sure that we can say these:

> A: I am hungry
>   B: Me, too
>   B: So am I
>   B: I am, too
>   B: I am hungry, too
>
> A: I am not hungry
>   B: Me, either
>   B: Neither am I
>   B: I am not, either
>   B: I am not hungry, either

My question is that

**Can we say "Tom, too / either" and "Him, too / either"?**

For example:

> A: Mary is hungry
>   B: Tom, too
>   B: Him, too (A & B know who is "him")
>
> A: Mary is not hungry
>   B: Tom, either
>   B: Him, either (A & B know who is "him")

Comment: "I am, either" and "I am hungry, either" are not correct and don't make sense.

Comment: Your forgot; Mary is hungry. ***So is Tom. So is he***. Tom is too. Tom, too and Him, too are not great.

Comment: When you ask **"Can we say?"** do you want to know if something is 1. grammatical, 2. acceptable, 3. idiomatic 4. borderline or 5. weird?

Answer (score 1):

I would not have used a comma in any of your example sentences. They are short enough not to require one.

You first set is OK, i.e., from 'I a hungry', to 'I am hungry, too'.

You second set are not all correct. Because the first person uses negation ('I am **not** hungry.'), anyone simply adding to that statement should use 'neither' rather than 'either'. People who answer the question for themselves use 'either' if they agree with the original answer. People who disagree with the original answer don't use 'either' or 'neither'. I have bolded changes but not deletions.

> A: I am not hungry.
>
> B: Me **neither/either**.     (Just joining in with A. Using 'neither' is preferred but 'either is also acceptable.)
>
> C: Neither am I.       (Just joining in with A. Either cannot be used in this case.)
>
> D: I am not (hungry) either.  (Answering for self, but agreeing. The word 'hungry' is optional. Neither cannot be used in this case.)
>
> E: I am not (**hungry**) either.          (Same as D)

For you third and fourth sets, I am assuming 5 people present, (Mary, you, him, A and B).

The third and fourth sets are OK, although no-one knows if A and B are hungry. In the fourth set B could have used 'either' or 'neither' in both responses.

Comment: You posted the answer before @Tom edited and fixed the "I am, either" issue, which means they realized their mistake.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  Thank you for alerting me to this change.  I have amended my answer to sentence E to take Tom's edit into account.

Answer (score 0):

I have have kept your structure, as it is easier on the eyes.

B: I am not hungry, either

B: Me, too [used a lot, colloquial, but OK]

B: So am I [preferred]

B: I am, too [preferred]

B: I am hungry, too [fine, but we do often contract this: I'm hungry too.]

A: I am not hungry

B: Me, either [colloquial, but it is used]

B: Neither/nor am I [preferred]

B: I'm not, either. [preferred]

B: I am not hungry, either [preferred], I'm not hungry either.

A: Mary is hungry

B: **Tom, too** [super colloquial]

B: Him, too, Her, too [super colloquial]

C: **So is he; So is Tom; Tom is too.** [preferred]

A: Mary is not hungry

B: Tom, either [super colloquial]

B: Him, either [super colloquial]

C: Neither/nor is Tom; Neither/nor is he. He isn't either. [preferred]

Super-colloquial is OK in some circumstances, but it does mark the speaker as somewhat uneducated. The super colloquial forms are often used by small children, too.

In general, when saying short things like I'm hungry, we use contracted forms unless there is a good reason not to, for example, for greater emphasis: But I **am** hungry.

Him, too and her, too can get rather awful in the plural: Them,too. So, I would advise being aware of them but not using them in your conversations.